# Helpful flags in my account

Tags: support, helpful-flags

There are a few badges like *Marshal* or *Deputy* which are granted after *raising 80 or 500 helpful flags*.

Is it possible to check number of *helpful flags* raised by me in my account pages?

**EDIT**

Column next to my gravatar looks as follows:

[image: Column]

Comment: This should be your flag summary page: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1916110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's in your profile, at the bottom of the column next to your gravatar.

Comment: Do you mean next to my gravatar? I do not have any information about helpful flags (I've attached a screenshot)

Comment: @Tom, Yes, it should be right above the 'hats' line.  Do you know if you have any helpful flags yet?

Comment: Yes, I have seen some under some comments. Will double check. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @tom, if you mean the flags on comments like these, those are NOT the helpful flags they're talking about.

Comment: @Tom - You don't currently have any flags that have been marked helpful. If you had at least one, you'd have the Citizen Patrol badge and would be able to see the count in your profile. As Lance mentioned, comment flags aren't treated the same as flags on questions and answers.

Comment: Ah I understand now. My apologies to anyone for confusing it! And many thanks for your help!